# Sending xml over http loses indents

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a fairly large XML file that I want to send over http to a device. The method I am using is creating the Xmldocument (called doc), converting the outerXML to a string, and sending it using an HttpWebResponse.

Here's a portion of the XML:

```
  <MotionDetection>
   <id>1</id>
   <enabled>true</enabled>
   <samplingInterval>2</samplingInterval>
   <startTriggerTime>500</startTriggerTime>
   <endTriggerTime>500</endTriggerTime>
   <regionType>grid</regionType>
     <Grid>
      <rowGranularity>15</rowGranularity>
      <columnGranularity>22</columnGranularity>
  </Grid>
</MotionDetection>
```

**The Problem:** Whenever I send my code over the internet, it doesn't accept it (giving me a bad request response) because the xml is missing the "indents" or vbCrlfs that cause the wireshark sniffer to see it like an xml instead of a bunch of strings smashed together.

Is there a way to send it using httpwebresponse so that those stay within the request? 
Other than, of course, breaking up the string and inserting it by "hand"?

Here's my current code, since I also tried it using an upload client instead of httpwebrequest.

```
        Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
        doc.Load("test.xml")
       Try
            Dim url = "http://" & currentCamera.ipaddr & "/Custom/Motion"
            Dim client As New WebClient
            client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential(currentCamera.Username, currentCamera.Password)
            Dim sentXml As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml)
            Dim response2 As Byte() = client.UploadData(url, "PUT", sentXml)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
```

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that missing whitespace in XML is causing an error. It may be you have a stray character(s) that is invalid as whitespace and outside of the XML elements. Try viewing the XML you are sending in an editor that understands XML like Notepad++. Also get the XML Tools Plugin which has some QA tools and pretty print formatting that will help you find errors. Saving the XML to a file and viewing in IE might show the error.

Comment: How about `Dim sentXml = File.ReadAllBytes("test.xml")`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found had to do with the encoding. Specifically this line:

```
  Dim sentXml As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml)
```

By changing the encoding from ASCII to UT8, the device accepted the xml and implemented changes. I.e.

```
   Dim sentXml As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc.OuterXml)
```

Apparently this was a much more accepted method by the network device.

Answer (score 0):

Removing spaces shouldn't break your XML file, but a wrong encoding will. Btw, is not bad removing spaces, it will save you some network data. The smaller the payload, the better.